# How do I use subdomains in redirect_uri for a consumer account in microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've set up an application for Microsoft Graph at `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/`.

This is for consumer accounts like `foo@outlook.com` (not an AD tenant)

When I add a redirect URI, it won't let subdomains of that URI work.

From the documentation (which refers to AD) this should work, but on the consumer side, it does not.

eg I register `https://example.com` and my app will attempt to redirect to `https://mycustomer.example.com`.

The result is that the `redirect_uri` doesn't match the app registration.

Anyone know how to make a subdomain work?

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly register each `redirect_uri`.

This includes each subdomain and page your app needs to redirect them to. Wildcards are not supported.

Comment: @marc-lafleur-msft Thanks for the response (MSFT Alum here). Will this ever change?  My app is multitenant eg it has lefleur.example.com and joshco.example.com  Am I going to have to have a public.example.com and do a redirect dance to link their msft accounts?

Comment: Normally you would have a single point of return and then redirect from there. You can pass the secondary redirect within the `state` query param. This value will be passed back as-is to your authentication endpoint.